(React Native) Problema con <Link> y <Pressable>
estoy creando mi primera aplicación y a la hora de crear los botones con estilos que reaccionan al pressed funcionan bien hasta que los meto dentro de un Link en ese momento el botón desaparece al no tener el Link estilos, y si le paso los estilos del Pressable no funcionan los estilos condicionales que se activan con el pressed. Este es mi código:
export const Button1 = () => (
        <Link href='/' asChild >
            <Pressable style={({ pressed }) => [{
                borderBottomWidth: pressed ? 2 : 4,
                backgroundColor: pressed ? '#77cde0' : '#69C7DC'},
                buttons.buttonBack, ]}>
                <Text style = {buttons.buttonText}>All</Text>
            </Pressable>
        </Link>
    )

¿Alguna idea de cómo conseguir esto? Muchas gracias

Hola, solo he seguido la forma de hacerlo que se indica en la misma documentación: https://docs.expo.dev/router/navigating-pages/ Hasta donde yo se, no puedo aplicar estilos a un Link con la función "pressed" es uno de las razones del porque hago esta pregunta.
